# How to declare multiple variables with almost the same name

Tags: c#, loops, variables, backgroundworker

I want to use multiple BackgroundWorkers for handling clients in a chat server (C#). But I don't know how to declare the multiple BackgroundWorkers. One backgroundworker for each client. I thought that maybe there is a way to declare them like this:

```css
for(int counter=0; ; counter++) {
  BackgroundWorker bw_counter=new BackgroundWorker();
  bw_counter.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

I want to replace "counter" in "bw_counter" with the actual value of "int counter". I don't know how to do this. Some people that have ideas?

I searched for a way to get it working but I couldn't thind a thread on SO that solves my problem.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this? Is it so that you can reference that individual background worker? Based on what it appears like your trying to do, I'd suggest using a `List<BackgroundWorker>`.

Comment: What do you mean by "reference that individual backgroundworker"? I want to have a different backgroundworker for each different client (those clients will connect form different pc's on the network or on ther networks) so I can send messages per user or to all of them or a specific amount of users

Comment: Basically, you need to say background worker 0 is attached to client A, worker 1 is attached to Client B, etc. Then you'd be able to say Send message to client A which is worker 0, or you can say send to all by iterating over the entire list. The three people that answered below are showing examples where you're referencing each individual background worker by index. Which sounds like what you're needing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is pretty much the definition of an array (or `IList`, at the very least).

```
var my_workers = new BackgroundWorker[counter];
```

Now you can refer to them by number:

```
my_workers[0] = new BackgroundWorker();
my_workers[0].RunWorkerAsync();
```

A simple way to create the array using your original code:

```
var workers = Enumerable.Range(0, counter)
    .Select(_ => {
        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        return bw; })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks this is actually what I need. I totally forgot the uses of arrays... The other answers will also do, but I think this one suits me best

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make a generic list of BackgroundWorker objects? This way you could easily reference them by number and track how many there are.

```
List<BackgroundWorker> bw = new List<BackgroundWorker>();
for(int counter=0; ; counter++) {
  bw.Add(new BackgroundWorker());
  bw[counter].RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stuff them in a list or dictionary so you can get them later. Dynamic variable naming is probably only available with some advanced stuffs (Reflection.Emit or similar).

```
var workers = new List<BackgroundWorker>();
for(int counter=0; ; counter++) 
{
  var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
  bw.RunWorkerAsync();
  workers.Add(bw);
}

var worker1 = workers.First();
```

Comment: Looks like you were slightly faster.

Comment: Nathan's comment came in first actually.